# Wear App started via Smartphone goes on stop

Tags: android, wear-os

In launching a wear app via the smartphone following this tutorial http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/a-guide-to-the-android-wear-message-api/152

As soon I launch it, the main activity goes in the stop condition. How can I keep it running?